# Can't find theme css

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Can someone take a look at my dummy site http://pinboard.comuf.com/Wordpress/

If you check beneath each post where it says

> 'Posted in Uncategorized | Tagged how, what, yes   | Leave a comment |'

you'll see that there are what seems to be border lines on top and bottom. However, I tried inspecting element and search for borders in the theme css but I can't find it. I want to edit those border lines.

Comment: Look harder and broaden your search. There are only a couple of elements and only a couple of css rules.

Comment: Oh! It's a background!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the background from your CSS.